# Find local copy of files in snapshot view

Tags: com, clearcase, clearcase-automation

I'm using the ClearCase Automation Library (CAL) in a tool that helps me keep track of unintegrated changes; now I'd like to extend the tool so I can also make checkins through it.

For this feature, I need to find the local copy of a Snapshot View. While I can ask CC which View is attached to a certain directory, I cannot seem to find a function to look up the local directory for a given View; also it appears as if the most reliable method to find out whether a Snapshot View exists locally is to compare the HostName property against the local computer name.

So: Given the IClearCase interface, how can I find all directories in which Snapshot Views exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirm that you cannot find the root directory of a snapshot view only knowing its view tag: a snapshot view can be loaded in several separate directories if you want.

The only link between your snapshot view and its root directory is the `.view.dat` hidden file which contains the uid of the view.

Plus, the hostname attached to a view has nothing to do with the fact it is loaded or not on a computer. It is the name of the *view server* (which can be your own desktop, or can be a centralized server). It is on that server that the `view.exe` process managing all ClearCase-related operations for that view.

So, with your script (like for instance a [perl script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193805/get-clearcase-snapshot-views-via-clearcase-automation-library-cal/1193934#1193934)), you don't really need CAL at first to find that view: you need first to be able to look the the `view.dat` file, extract the uid, and then check if it is the same than the [view uid (`lsview -l -full -pro`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830412/getting-view-owner-creator-with-rational-clearcase-automation-library-cal/831673#831673) you are looking for.

Comment: So my only choice seems to be to scan a configurable path for directories that do not give an error when passed to the directory -> View resolver...

Comment: @SimonRichter: rather than trying lots of directories, it is best to try only the one with the hidden file '`view.dat`'.

Comment: And that, ladies and gentlemen of SO, was my **5000th answer** (in 37 months), eight months after the [4000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953561). And before that: [3000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074849), [2000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027976) and [1000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665252)