# How to create view from latest stream on clear case using command

Tags: shell, clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

I'm currently working on a power shell script to automate the clear case tool. However, I am new to the new clear case tool. I require the clear case tool commands listed below.

1. Create a view from the latest stream.
2. Mount the created view on the local machine

Answer (score 0):

"Mounting the view" means a dynamic view. (Meaning MVFS is activated on your Windows PC, and you have a `M:\` drive)

See "[How to associate a clearcase view with stream or vob?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13363572/6309)", and [`cleartool mkview`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rational-clearcase/8.0.1?topic=ucm-mkview)

```
cleartool mkview -tag myview -stream MyStream@/vobs:MyPVob \\path\to\viewstorage\your-username_dynview.vws
```

See also "[Creation of Integration View](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33217727/6309)".

Comment: Hi VonC

What is myview and MyStream pointed out, can you please provided any example command and show to get those keywords

Comment: @max You need to replace `MyView` with the name of your View, and `MyStream` with the name of your Stream, and `MyPVob` with the name of your PVob. In other words, the example is in the answer, with placeholder values to be replaced accordingly.

Comment: Hi VonC

How to verify view's occurence before creation? it should return a boolean value

Comment: @max I mentioned that in 2011, I believe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8602428/6309