# Clearcase, How to change working directory view?

Tags: linux, clearcase

I'm using clearcase version 8.0.1.00.

`Pwv` gives me:

```
Working directory view: Core
Set view: ** NONE **
```

I want this:

```
Working directory view: Core64
Set view: ** NONE **
```

There already exists a `Core64` view but using `setview` it gives me:

```
cleartool: Error: You cannot use the "setview" command with a snapshot view.
```

I am doing this in the path of `BCPL/Core64/BCVOB/Admin/builds`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Core64` is a [snapshot view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925378/6309), all you need to do is to go (cd) to its root folder (which can be anywhere you decided to create it).
See also "[Difference between Snapshot and Dynamic Views](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21177694)"

Then a `cleartool pwv` would give you Core64.
It would do so in any folder or subfolder of the root folder of the `Core64` view. But `ClearCase` itself does not know *where* that root folder is.
See "[How to find the view location in my Linux home dir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10275856/6309)".
As I mentioned in "[Find local copy of files in snapshot view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7917396/6309)":

> The only link between your snapshot view and its root directory is the `.view.dat` hidden file which contains the `uuid` of the snapshot view.

Note: even if `Core64` was a dynamic view, I would recommend *not* to use `cleartool setview` (but the full path of a dynamic view: `/view/Core64/vobs/aVob`). See "[working in `/vobs/some/path` versus `/view/view-tag-name/vobs/some/path`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40347698/6309)"
Again, that path is not the right one here, since `Core64` is a snapshot view, and `/view` is a mounting point for dynamic views.

Comment: I want the directory BCPL/Core64/BCVOB/Admin/builds to use core64 view.
By changing the directory with cd that doesn't accomplish that. I know where the global path view is stored "/views/user/Core64.vws", I just want clearcase to use that view in THIS directory. Thanks.

Comment: @JosephLuce All you need to do is to rename `builds` into another name, and move/rename your other folder (the one which is the root folder of the `Core64` snapshot view) into  `BCPL/Core64/BCVOB/Admin/builds`.

Comment: BCPL/Core64/BCVOB/Admin/builds is loaded from a config spec, but the config spec is loaded using Core view. I don't believe moving folders is correct. Kinda scared this will break things if I do so. Then again I have no clue how clearcase works, I'm treading lightly.

Comment: @JosephLuce That will bread *nothing* for ClearCase. ClearCase does not care where the snapshot view is. ClearCase does not associate a path to a config spec. All that ClearCase checks is the `.view.dat` hidden file in order to know which snapshot view (and config spec) to use. If you want, you could simply switch the two hidden `.view.dat` files.