# Code to get list of directories in Clearcase

Tags: clearcase

I have a directories that I manage using Clearcase. Is there a way to get a list of directories in IBM Clearcase in a table?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use [`cleartool find`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm) in order to get a list of directories (you would still need to put the output of that command in a table though).
You need to be in a ClearCase view to execute it.

```
cd /path/to/view/aVob/aDirectory
cleartool find . -type d -print
```

The '`-type d`' will limit the results to directories only.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But can you help me find the view location in windows? There are too many folders and I am not sure where the view is located. What is the default location of the view?

Comment: @amirshadaab for dynamic views, `m:\aView` (if the view is started: `cleartool startview aView`). Snapshot views can be anywhere: make a search for `.view.dat` hidden files: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7917396/6309. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/2925378/6309.