# How to create OLE Automation to be used with ClearExplorer

Tags: clearcase

In the following http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21158221
there is a mention of COMMAND TYPE as **OLE Automation**.
Can you please help me with an example of **OLE Automation** for ClearExplorer tool?

Answer (score 0):

OLE automation is generally done with the **[CAL (ClearCase Automation Library)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21123249)**, which provides a set of COM interfaces to ClearCase on the Windows 32-bit platforms.

> These interfaces are intended both as an integration platform and also as an API that can be used to extend or customize ClearCase.
>   CAL can also be used to develop stand alone applications, write scripts, or embed macros in other applications that interact with ClearCase on some level.

I have used it in VB scripts in:

- "[Get ClearCase Snapshot Views via ClearCase Automation Library (CAL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1193934/6309)"
- "[Getting View Owner/Creator with Rational ClearCase Automation Library (CAL)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/831673/6309)"
- "[How do I get latest clearcase label programmatically from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/269624/6309)"

Comment: My question was about the APP NOTE from IBM as mentioned for clearmenuadmin tool. Not about CAL example. In the ClearMenuAdmin App Note, if you see "Defining Menu Item Properties" section, there is a mention of COMMAND TYPE table which contains OLE Automation as one of the entry.
Answer you provided is basically an EXECUTABLE type and not OLE Automation from the perspective of clearmenuadmin tool I suppose once you build your application.