# Check ClearCase version existence in VBA

Tags: vba, clearcase

One of my Excel VBA scripts cycles through all the versions of a particular ClearCase element to see if it was merged. This fails when a particular version was deleted using an **rmver** (using destructive deletes is not recommended but we do resort to this on rare occasions to get a developer out of a dependency).

In DOS, the following works perfectly:

```
IF EXIST M:\View\LAMI\build.xml@@\main\lc_adhoc_dev\3 ECHO Yes
Yes
```

To do this in VBA, I tried using the Dir method to check for the presence of a particular version:

```
Dim elementVersion As String
elementVersion = "M:\View\LAMI\build.xml@@\main\lc_adhoc_dev\3"

If Len(Dir(elementVersion)) > 0 Then
  ' Version exists
Else
  ' Version does not exist
End If
```

However, that results in an error "Bad file name or number":

I also tried the FileExists method of the fso object:

```
Dim elementVersion As String
elementVersion = "M:\View\LAMI\build.xml@@\main\lc_adhoc_dev\3"
Dim fsoObj As Object
Set fsoObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If fsoObj.FileExists(elementVersion) = True Then
  ' Version exists
Else
  ' Version does not exist
End If
```

However, that call always returns False. It appears all these methods have issues with the ClearCase MVFS virtual M: drive. Is there anything else I could  try?

Comment: I'll post an answer in a few hours, but check out `cleartool get` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5381646/6309): if you can get and copy an old version to your C:\ drive, then that version exists. If the `cleartool get` fails... the version does not exist.

Comment: cleartool get only works for files. I need to check non-existing versions of directories too (I updated my question: changed "file" to "element"). Also,

Comment: Also, I'm trying not to have to rely on the Err object, i.e. not use a cleartool command that fails when it encounters a non-existing version (such as get or descr).

Comment: I was about to suggest describe ;)

Comment: In your case you should rely on err

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying not to have to rely on the [`Err` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka13cy19(v=vs.90).aspx), i.e. not use a `cleartool` command that fails when it encounters a non-existing version (such as get or descr).

That is *precisely* what you should rely on, unless you have constraint (like testing thousands of elements per second, or other performance bottleneck)

[`cleartool describe`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm) can be applied on an [extended pathname](https://stackoverflow.com/a/988904/6309) and will fail if it does not exist.

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348071/check-clearcase-version-existence-in-vba/43353076?noredirect=1#comment73774357_43353076) by [Brian Cowan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4223401/brian-cowan), you can check if Excel VBA can call commands from the [ClearCase Automation Library (**CAL**)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21123249).
I have [used CAL in VB Script before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31296275/6309).

Comment: RIght: I want to make sure a particular version exists before running a describe on it!
Interesting that this (checking for the existence of a particular version without using error handlers) can be done in DOS Batch and  not in VBA.
Guess I have no choice but to use the Err object.

Comment: @Jozef I understand. But here, describe is used bith to check if it exists, and, if it does, to describe it.

Comment: If you're using 32-bit Excel, you might want to look at the ClearCase Automation Library (CAL). The "doc" is the cc_cal.chm file in C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin... This unfortunately mean that you need to install the help file viewer.

Comment: @VonC I'm using CAL too in these scripts (I pass most commands through a cleartool object.) 
I just wanted to prevent a cleartool descr command from generating an error when a particular version does not exist. Since there apparently is no way to do that my original question was answered. I check the value of Err.Number to see if a version exists and no longer exit the script when it doesn't.