# How to Check In , Check Out , Undo Check Out in IBM Rational ClearCase (SCM) using the File Path in C#?

Tags: c#, clearcase

From using file path, I like check in, check out and undo check out of that file in C#.
Is it possible to do that?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You appear to be talking about some sort of subversioning tool but I can't work out what you're actually asking... Could you please clarify?

Comment: @Smudge202: @ratty was talking about ClearCase: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/clearcase/info . I got this ;)

Comment: @VonC I hadn't noticed the tag before. Time for another coffee ^^  Cheers ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a direct C# API, only a set of COM interfaces through the **[Rational ClearCase Automation Library (CAL)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/06/0207_joshi/index.html)**.
So as in "[How do I get latest clearcase label programmatically from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268595/how-do-i-get-latest-clearcase-label-programmatically-from-c/269624#269624)", it is better to wrap those checkout/checkin/unco operations in VB scripts, and [call them from your C# program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200422/how-to-call-a-vbscript-file-in-a-c-application).